NgRX signal store custom named store feature
I have a NgRX signal store like so:
type ResultType = any;
export const MyCollectionsStore = signalStore(
  withState<{
    loading: boolean;
    loadingError: string | null;
    result: ResultType | null;
  }>({
    loading: false,
    loadingError: null,
    result: null,
  }),
  withMethods((store, collectionsApiService = inject(CollectionsService)) => ({
    loadPage: rxMethod<{ page: number; itemsPerPage: number }>(
      pipe(
        tap(() => patchState(store, { loading: true, loadingError: null })),
        switchMap(({ page, itemsPerPage }) => {
          return collectionsApiService
            .getMyCollections(page, itemsPerPage)
            .pipe(
              tapResponse({
                next: (result) => patchState(store, { result }),
                error: (e) => patchState(store, { loadingError: `${e}` }),
                finalize: () => patchState(store, { loading: false }),
              }),
            );
        }),
      ),
    ),
  })),
);

I would like to extract the withState and withMethods calls in a separate signalStoreFeature, but I want it to accept a name, like the named entity collections of the withEntities feature.
I figured out the state, but I'm still struggling on the methods part:
export type StatefulMethodResultState<TResult extends object> = {
  loading: boolean;
  loadingError: string | null;
  result: TResult | null;
};

export type NamedStatefulMethodResultState<
  TResult extends object,
  TName extends string,
> = {
  [K in TName as `${K}State`]: StatefulMethodResultState<TResult>;
};

export const withStatefulMethodResult = <
  TResult extends object,
  TName extends string,
>(
  method: (...params: any) => any,
  name: TName,
) => {
  return signalStoreFeature(
    withState<NamedStatefulMethodResultState<TResult, TName>>({
      [`${name}State`]: {
        loading: false,
        loadingError: null,
        result: null,
      },
    } as NamedStatefulMethodResultState<TResult, TName>),
    withMethods((store) => ({
      [name]: () => method(store),
    })),
  );
};

I'm not sure what type I need to specify on the method parameter. Also I obviously would like to be able to inject stuff in the method when I declare it, so the consuming code would look something like this:
withStatefulMethodResult(
  (
    store,
    collectionsApiService = inject(CollectionsService),
  ) =>
    pipe(
      tap(() => patchState(store, { loadPageState: { loading: true, loadingError: null } })),
      switchMap(({ page, itemsPerPage }) => {
        return collectionsApiService.getMyCollections(page, itemsPerPage).pipe(
          tapResponse({
            next: (result) => patchState(store, { loadPageState: { result } }),
            error: (e) => patchState(store, { loadPageState: { loadingError: `${e}` } }),
            finalize: () => patchState(store, { loadPageState: { loading: false } }),
          }),
        );
      }),
    ),
  'loadPage',
);

Ideally I would like an answer for NgRX, but if NgRX isn't the right tool for this job I'm open to other suggestions.
